# Error when execute SQL from dot net core 7 cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.FormattableString'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, c#-7.0

I work on .net core 7 entity framework core . I get error when run my application on this function

error say `cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.FormattableString'`

```
public List<ApplicationDto> ListOfApplications(ApplicationsFilterDto emp)
        {
            var appList = _context.Database.ExecuteSql($"select ApplicationsData.ApplicationID as ApplicationId,Application_Name as ApplicationName,CommonName,d.DetailsName as TypeOfApplication,AccessType,d.DetailsName Criticality,o.OwnerName as ApplicationOwner,DRRequired,se.[DB_Name] as [DataBase] from ApplicationsData left join [dbo].[Details] d with(nolock) on d.ID=ApplicationsData.ApplicationType and d.HeaderId=6 left join [dbo].[Details] d2 with(nolock) on d2.ID=ApplicationsData.Criticality and d2.HeaderId=7\r\nleft join dbo.[Owner] o with(nolock) on o.ApplicationId=ApplicationsData.ApplicationID\r\nleft join dbo.[DataBase] se with(nolock) on se.ServerID=ApplicationsData.ServerId where ApplicationsData.ServerId=" + emp.serverID + " OR SE.[DBID]=" + emp.databaseId + " OR o.OwnerId=" + emp.ownerId + "");
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            return appList;  
       }
```

return model as below :

```
public class ApplicationDto
    {
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string CommonName { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfApplication { get; set; }
        public string AccessType { get; set; }
        public string Criticality { get; set; }
        public string DataBase { get; set; }
        public string BSSVServer { get; set; }
        public string DRRequired { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationOwner { get; set; }


    }
```

filter model I use it

```
public class ApplicationsFilterDto
    {
        public int serverID { get; set; }
        public int ownerId { get; set; }
        public int databaseId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: FromSqlInterpolated it not avilable

Comment: What is the reason to use SQL if you have LINQ? `ExecuteSql` do not query anything it just executes script. Anyway, read documentation [SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Faster Performance in some cases. But not for this one like queries.

Comment: yes i need to execute query so how to solve issue of execute sql please

Comment: @AVTUNEY, for performance OP can use [Compiled Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities) same speed but better maintainability.

Comment: can you help me writing answer by code

Comment: Answer to what? You have `SELECT` query but used `ExecuteSql` which returns nothing. With EF Core 7 you cannot retrieve such result. You have to use Dapper or write LINQ query which is simple.

Comment: ok i need to execute sql query so can you tell me how to execute it wih any way please

Comment: There are a few things wrong here. FormattableStrings `$"..."` are not strings so they don't have `+` operators. `ExecuteSql()` only returns a row count so if you're expecting to return results - as your method signature suggests - you probably want to use `FromSql()` instead.

Comment: can you tell me how to write please ExecuteSql()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because you are trying to pass a string directly into the `ExecuteSql()` method.

Using `FromSqlInterpolated()` instead of `ExecuteSql()` should fix it.